# Need help multiplying each number in the array by the number after it, and getting those results to show up

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

right now I have it so you can input a number into an array and then that number is displayed in descending order. What i'm having trouble with though, is c. For example, if the array was 2,4,6,3, the result would be 8, 18. So far, not sure if my code is even correct, and if it is, how to get the results of multiplying each number in the array by the number after it into a second array called "multNumbers", and how to get those results to show up on the web page.

Here is my code so far
`enter code here`https://codepen.io/kaiokokokk/pen/XWWQQzj

Comment: How do you get to a desired second element of `18` in your result? Are you always consuming pairs, so the result is half the length of the input? Also, it's interesting, that you have a problem with "c", but we can't read your homework assignment text, if you don't post it.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a job for reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):
Reduce is an array function that iterates over all the elements of the array and takes a reducer function.
The reducer function takes four arguments, we are going to give it only two, the accumulator which will keep the running total, and the current value, which is the current value of the array as the reduce function iterates over all the array's elements.

Your reducer function's returned value is assigned to the accumulator, whose value is remembered across each iteration throughout the array and ultimately becomes the final, single resulting value.

```
let numbers = [2,3,4,5]
    function MultiplyNumbers() {
        const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator * currentValue;
        window.alert(numbers.reduce(reducer));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code, only changes required in MultiplyNumbers function:

```js
     let numbers = [];
        let multNumbers = [];

        function addToList(event) {
            const inputField = document.getElementById("mad");
            const inputValue = Number(inputField.value);


            numbers.push(inputValue)


            numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
                return b - a
            });


            renderList()


            inputField.value = ""
        }

        function renderList() {
            var domList = "";

            for (let y = 0; y < numbers.length; y++) {
                domList += "Element " + y + " = " + numbers[y] + "<br/>";
            }

            document.getElementById("sadness").innerHTML = domList;
        }

        function MultiplyNumbers() {
            var sum = 1, result =[];
            if(numbers.length > 1 ) {
             for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                 i<numbers.length-1 && result.push(numbers[i] * numbers[i+1]);
             }
            }
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        }
```

```html
<input class="rising" type="text" id="mad">
    <input type="button" class="button" id="button1" value="Add in descending order" onclick="addToList();">
    <input type="button" class="button" id="button2" value="Multiply numbers" onclick="MultiplyNumbers();">
   



    <hr />
    <p id="sadness" class="animal"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I clearly understood, the first button should order input numbers and the second one should multiply them in pairs.

With ordering function was a little problem (an array wasn't splitted from input field) and `renderList` was working with global variable, that's why was some problem with showing resultant `Element`'s.

`MultiplyNumbers` function hasn't checking on odd number of elements, that not allowed to get the correct resultant values.

Check snippet and let me know if something I've misunderstood.

```js
  function descOrderList(event) {
        const inputField = document.getElementById("mad");
        var temp = inputField.value.split(",");
                 
        temp.sort(function(a, b) {
             return b - a
        });

        renderList(temp);

        inputField.value = temp;
 }
     
 function MultiplyNumbers() {
        let numbers = [];
        let multNumbers = [];
        const inputField = document.getElementById("mad").value; 
        var temp = inputField.split(",");
                
        if (temp.length % 2 == 0){
        let actions = temp.length / 2;
                    
           for(let i = 0; i < actions; i++){ 
               var tsum = (isNaN(temp[i*2]) || isNaN(temp[i*2+1])) ? 0 : Number(temp[i*2]) * Number(temp[i*2+1]);
               multNumbers.push(tsum);
           }
           renderList(multNumbers);   // is you wish
           document.getElementById("mad").value = multNumbers;
        } 
 }

 function renderList(nums) {
       var domList = "";

       for (let y = 0; y < nums.length; y++) {
           domList += "Element " + y + " = " + nums[y] + "<br/>"; 
       }

       document.getElementById("sadness").innerHTML = domList;
 }
```

```html
    <input class="rising" type="text" id="mad">
    <input type="button" value="Add in descending order" onclick="descOrderList();">
    <input type="button" value="Multiply numbers" onclick="MultiplyNumbers();">
     
        <hr />
        <p id="sadness" class="animal"></p>
```